# Display text file from line 100 to line 200 in linux Terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

Let's say I have a text file called results.txt and the only information that I need is in lines 100 to 200. I want to display this text in Ubuntu Terminal. What is the best solution?

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use `cat` and `grep` command:

```
cat -n filename | grep -A100 '\b100\b'
```

It means search for 100th line and show the following 100 lines